# Difficulty with mounting a filesystem in SaltStack

Tags: salt-stack

I'm migrating our ansible playbooks to Salt, and I'm having some issues with mounting a filesystem.

The ansible playbook is as follows:

```
- name: Create mount point.
  file: name=/mnt/nfs state=directory

- name: Mount dat.
  mount: name=/mnt/nfs src=nfs-1:/data/nfs fstype=nfs state=mounted
```

This is the salt state equivalent I have so far, which fails miserably:

```
create_mount_point:
  file.directory:
    - name: /mnt/nfs

mount_dat:
  mount.mounted:
    - name: /mnt/nfs
    - device: nfs-1:/data/nfs
    - mkmnt: True
    - fstype: nfs
    - require:
      - file: create_mount_point
```

Now I admit I don't know much about mounting filesystems in Ubuntu. The error I get from the above is:

```
ID: mount_dat
Function: mount.mounted
    Name: /mnt/nfs
  Result: False
 Comment: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on nfs-1:/data/nfs,
                 missing codepage or helper program, or other error
                 (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might
                 need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program)

                 In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
                 dmesg | tail or so.
 Started: 00:26:26.717631
Duration: 141.096 ms
 Changes:
```

perhaps someone could point me in the right direction? Not sure whether the suggestion to use a 'helper program' is useful in this context, and if so how one would do it with the `mount.mounted` state.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you miss a package with the filesystem tools for nfs. Based on the [ubuntu docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-file-system.html) it is called `nfs-common`.

Some debugging steps that might help here:

- Connect to a minion that should be able to mount that and run `salt-call state.sls [name of your mount sls] -l debug`.
- Read the output and search for the executed `mount` command
- Try to mount manually

Comment: Thanks @dahrens, i'll check it out